# Create an Account class in Python 3

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I was wondering if somebody could help me out with this? I'm using python 3 and I'm looking to do this. I'm hopelessly lost though. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The Account class should contain the following
A private int data field named id for the account with a default value of 0.

A private double data field named balance for the account with a default value of 0.

A private double data field named annualInterestRate that stores the current interest rate with a default value of 0. Assume all accounts have the same interest rate.

A private Date data field named dateCreated that stores the date when the account was created.

A no-argument constructor that creates a default account.

A constructor that creates an account with the specified id and initial balance.

The accessor and mutator methods for id, balance, and annualInterestRate.

The accessor method for dateCreated.

A method named getMonthlyInterestRate() that returns the monthly interest rate.

A method named withdraw that withdraws a specified amount from the account.

A method named deposit that deposits a specified amount to the account.

Implement the class. Write a test program that create an Account object with an account ID of 1122, a balance of $20,000, and an annual interest rate of 4.5%. Use the withdraw method to withdraw $2,500, use the deposit method to deposit $3,000, and print the balance, the monthly interest, and the date when this account was created.

The code I have now is:

```
class Account:

    def __init__(self):
        self.balance=balance

    def getMonthlyInterestRate(self):
        return (annualInterest/100)

    def getMonthlyInterest(self):
        return blanace * monthlyInterestRate
```

Now the other code I have is:

```
from Account import Account

def main():

    account = Account()
    account.getMonthlyInterestRate(4.5)

    print("Beginning Balance: ", account.balance)
    print("Monthly Interest Rate: ", account.getMonthlyInterestRate)
    print("Monthly Interest: ", account.getMonthlyInterest)

main()
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: How do I set this up? When I run the code now, I get an error saying, "global name 'balance' is not defined."
I am especially confused about the creating an account ID of 1122.

Comment: no, this isn't homework. I'm just trying to learn python. It's from a book a purchased.

Comment: This task sounds like it's intended for somebody programming in a language other than Python. There are a bunch of things mentioned that either don't exist in Python at all (like private, typed variables) or which don't work the same way in Python that they do in other languages (multiple constructors with different numbers of arguments). It will be very hard to learn Python if you're working out of a Java or C++ book!

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your class to be like that:

```
 class Account:

    def __init__(self, balance, annual_interest_rate):
        self.balance=balance
        self.annualInterest = annual_interest_rate

    def getMonthlyInterestRate(self):
        return (self.annualInterest/100)

    def getMonthlyInterest(self):
        return self.balance * self.getMonthlyInterestRate()
```

notice that I've passed balance and annual interest rate as constructor arguments
So to instantiate an account object:

```
account = Account(200, 5)
```

Comment: I keep getting a <bound method Account.getMonthly.... at 0x0000000319BF60> display.

Comment: you need to add the rounded brackets --> 
print("Monthly Interest Rate: ", account.getMonthlyInterestRate())
print("Monthly Interest: ", account.getMonthlyInterest())

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at your code-

```
class Account:

    def __init__(self):
        self.balance=balance
```

This is your constructor.  It sets up the default state of an instance of your class- when you build an Account, this method will run.  Inside this method, self refers to the specific account you are setting up.  If you call

```
myaccount = Account()
```

myaccount.balance will be equal to whatever we set it to.  Here is where we get to the first problem- you set self.balance = balance.... but balance doesn't equal anything!  You could, however have

```
def __init__(self):
    self.balance = 0
    self.id = 0
    self.annualInterestRate = 0
```

and so on, to set up those variables with their default values.

Lets look at your next method-

```
def getMonthlyInterestRate(self):
    return (annualInterest/100)
```

here, you set up a method that when you call myaccount.getMonthlyInterestRate() should return the rate.  However, you don't specify the variable to pull from.  That should be 
    return self.annualInterestRate/100
because you want the interest from THIS account.

Now your last class method-

```
def getMonthlyInterest(self):
    return blanace * monthlyInterestRate
```

this has two problems.  First, it should be self.balance- because it is THIS account's balance you want.  Second is that monthlyInterestRate is not a variable- it is a derived value that you have a function for.  you can call that function though...

```
return balance * getMonthlyInterestRate()
```

Looking at your main function-

```
account.getMonthlyInterestRate(4.5)
```

you feed that interest rate into the function... but the function does not take any arguments!  If you want to set the rate you would use

```
account.annualInterestRate = 4.5
```

or create a SET interest rate function that takes an argument and then sets the variable to the appropriate value.  This would be

```
def setInterest(self, rate):
    self.annualInterestRate = rate
```

The same logic will go for the rest of your requirements... good luck with Python :)